# Using '<%# Eval("item") %>'; Handling Null Value and showing 0 against

Tags: asp.net, dataitem

If dataitem is `Null` I want to show `0`

```
<asp:Label ID="Label18" Text='<%# Eval("item") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can also create a public method on the page then call that from the code-in-front.

e.g. if using C#:

```
public string ProcessMyDataItem(object myValue)
{
  if (myValue == null)
  {
     return "0 value";
  }

  return myValue.ToString();
}
```

Then the label in the code-in-front will be something like:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label18" Text='<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("item")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Sorry, haven't tested this code so can't guarantee I got the syntax of "`<%# ProcessMyDataItem(Eval("item")) %>`" entirely correct.

Comment: I did the check in the <%# %> tags and == null didn't identify the null returns; I had to use == DBNull.Value.

Comment: Where would I add that to my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237555/why-empty-cell-throws-an-error-during-sql-stored-procedure-execution

Comment: Worth an additional check to see if myValue.ToString() is empty as well. For example, Eval("MyDate", "{0:d}") gives an empty string if MyDate is a nullable DateTime object.

Answer (score 52):

I'm using this for string values:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Data").ToString()) ? "0" : Eval("Data"))%>
```

You can also use following for nullable values:

```
<%#(Eval("Data") == null ? "0" : Eval("Data"))%>
```

Also if you're using .net 4.5 and above I suggest you use [strongly typed data binding](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="odsUsers" ItemType="Entity.User">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Item.Title %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Won't this throw an exception if Eval("Data") is null?

Comment: If the value is DBNull.Value then it won't. Example: object a = DBNull.Value; Response.Write(a.ToString());

Answer (score 13):

I use the following for VB.Net:

```
<%# If(Eval("item").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "0 value", Eval("item")) %>
```

Comment: Where would I add that to my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237555/why-empty-cell-throws-an-error-during-sql-stored-procedure-execution

Answer (score 4):

It should work as well

```
Eval("item") == null?"0": Eval("item");
```

Answer (score 3):

Moreover, you can use (x = Eval("item") ?? 0) in this case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ASP.NET very well, but can you use the ternary operator?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Something like:
    (x=Eval("item")) == Null ? 0 : x

Answer (score 1):

Use IIF.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label18" Text='<%# IIF(Eval("item") Is DBNull.Value,"0", Eval("item") %>' 
runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code it might be useful -

```
<%# ((DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageFilename").ToString()=="") ? "" :"<a
 href="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "link")+"><img
 src='/Images/Products/"+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
 "ImageFilename")+"' border='0' /></a>")%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Used a modified version of Jason's answer:

```
public string ProcessMyDataItem(object myValue)
{
  if (myValue.ToString().Length < 1)
  {
     return "0 value";
  }

  return myValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `<%# Eval("item") %>` with `<%# If(Eval("item"), "0 value") %>` (or `<%# Eval("item") ?? "0 value" %>`, when using C#).

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but "<%# If(Eval("item"), "0 value") %>" looks a bit odd. Not sure you can actually use an If statement with Eval like that, and wouldn't the result just be a True/False returned?

Comment: No, that's the VB.NET binary `If` operator: `If(value, valueIfNull)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and it works well for both null and empty situations :

```
'<%# (Eval("item")=="" || Eval("item")==null) ? "0" : Eval("item")%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for VB.net, especially if the value is a boolean:

```
<%# IIf(Eval("mydata").Equals(DBNull.Value), 0, Eval("mydata"))%>
```

For example, use this to automatically check or uncheck a checkbox with inline IIF eval:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="mycheckbox" runat="server" Checked='<%# IIf(Eval("mydata").Equals(DBNull.Value), 0, Eval("mydata"))%>' />
```

The other method with .ToString will cause an error trying to convert the DBnull to a boolean.