# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, gridview

i want to set visibility on or off on PendingApproval value but in database PendingApprovalfield is allow null true so I got error here is code

I got this error Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.

```
 style="margin-left:6px; margin-top:auto; display:<%#  IIf(CTYPE(Eval("PendingApproval"),Integer) = 1, "block", "none")%>"
```

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979806/using-evalitem-handling-null-value-and-showing-0-against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I am assuming if the value is NULL then visibility need to set off

```
style="margin-left:6px; margin-top:auto; display:<%# IIf(Eval("PendingApproval")=DBNull.value,"none", IIf(Eval("PendingApproval") = 1, "block", "none"))%>"
```

A suggestion, in the query used to pull the report can you apply ISNULL() function like below:

```
SELECT col1, ISNULL(PendingApproval,0), ..., coln FROM TABLE1
```

By this way you will get value 0 for NULL and your old code will work well without comparing for DBNull.value

Comment: I use this but got error  BC30452: Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Object' and 'System.DBNull'. also use == but its also not works

Answer (score 0):

To prevent that error you try this ..

```
style="margin-left:6px; margin-top:auto; display:<%#Iif(Eval("PendingApproval") Is Null,"none",IIf(CTYPE(Eval("PendingApproval"),Integer) = 1, "block", "none"))%>"
```