# Input string was not in a correct format. if user did not insert any value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have fuction to show the total of items in footer of GridView by entering the values from TextBox and its works fine with me but if user forget to enter value and do inserting I have this error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I want to set default value to that TextBox "Zero" so if the user did not enter any value it will take it as default value I mean Zero.

//The fuction code is

```
<script runat="server">
Dim TotalUnitPrice As Decimal = 0.0
Function GetUnitPrice(ByVal Price As Decimal) As Decimal
    TotalUnitPrice += Price
    Return Price
End Function
Function GetTotal() As Decimal
    Return TotalUnitPrice
End Function  
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Creditor" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="True">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# GetUnitPrice(decimal.Parse(Eval("tabDebit").ToString())).ToString()  %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <%# GetTotal().ToString()%>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post:  [Using '<%# Eval(“item”) %>'; Handling Null Value and showing 0 against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979806/using-evalitem-handling-null-value-and-showing-0-against)

Something like - <%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Data").ToString()) ? "0" : Eval("Data"))%>

Comment: Can you please explain how this post can be a answer to this question??

Comment: All right but this will give problems if the user doesn't input a valid decimal number

Comment: sure dude its the Idea I create function that check if the entered value is null if u wanna code i will give it to u

Comment: you can prevent user by using regular expression validator

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in ASP.NET but probably it will be a lot easier if your functions receive a string and return a string

```
...aspx.vb....
Dim TotalUnitPrice As Decimal = 0.0
Function GetUnitPrice(ByVal Price As String) As String
    Dim temp As Decimal = 0.0
    if decimal.TryParse(Price, out temp) Then
         TotalUnitPrice += temp
    End If
    Return temp.ToString()
End Function
Function GetTotal() As String
    Return TotalUnitPrice.ToString()
End Function

....aspx....
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# GetUnitPrice(Eval("tabDebit"))  %>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <%# GetTotal()%>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Let see if someone more experienced in ASP.NET points to a better way to do it

Comment: TY I will give it try to see the result