# (SQL) Efficient way of replacing of NULL values in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, winforms

I have a database table like this on `SQL Server`:

```
USER   PASSWORD
1      samplepassword
2      NULL
3      NULL
4      sample_password
```

I want to replace the `NULL` values in the PASSWORD column, along with other columns, with values like '(Not set)' or '-' upon displaying it to the user in a `DataGridView`.

There are three ways I know of in achieving this.  First is to use the `NullValue` property of the column's `DefaultCellStyle`.  The concern with this method is that the designer would create multiple copies of the same DefaultCellStyle - one per column.

Then there's the `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView`.  Lastly, the replacing can be done on the SQL statement itself, ala `ISNULL(password, '(Not set)')`.

Considering that this DataGridView can be filtered afterwards by the user (e.g. show only those without a password), what is the more suggested way in doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: for handle in DataGridView ,check this link.
[Check null in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979806/using-evalitem-handling-null-value-and-showing-0-against)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting is not `SQL server` responsibility, keep formatting in your UI code.

Use `DefaultCellStyle` and create instance of `DefaultCellStyle` in the code and set same instance to the all columns of datagridview manually.

Or assign only `NullValue` property to already existed styles

```
const string NULL_VALUE = "not set";
DataGridView.Columns["ColumnName1"].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = NULL_VALUE;
DataGridView.Columns["ColumnName2"].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = NULL_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(YourColumn, 'yourcharacter' ) FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on SQL Server but on MySQL I wold do the following

```
SELECT USER, IF(PASSWORD IS NULL,'Not Set', PASSWORD) AS PASSWORD FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a JavaScript or jQuery function after your DataGridView load, to find empty values from DataGridView and replace it with "(Not set)" or "-".

OR

Update your dataset values which are empty with values "-".

Comment: I'd put it at the frontend as well. Exactly how to change the values depends on what frameworks are at play there though. If AngularJs or similar framework it could be done in the controller before loading the grid with data, would probably be way easier that way

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is the best one from a paradigm standpoint, though you can also handle this by creating a helper function to handle nulls.  This will make your default values something you can change based on your datatype.  It also lets you manage nulls before they ever touch the UI, but without affecting your queries, which is essential if you have to handle mathematics before displaying output.

```
public static dynamic NullCheck(object d, dynamic default)
{      
      return DbNull.Value == d ? default : d;
}
```

Just be ready to cast the result as needed in your code, such as `((foo)(Nullcheck(foo, bar)))`.